# Get maximum edges count connected to a node in a graph

Tags: c++, graph

I made a program which adds nodes and edges between those nodes.Now i want to find which node has the maximum count of edges connected to it.Here is my code:

```
    const int N = 15;

struct graf {
    int key;
    graf *next;
};




void init(graf *gr[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++) {
        gr[i] = NULL;
    }
}

int search_node(graf *gr[], int c) {
    int flag = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++) {
        if (gr[i]) {
            if (gr[i]->key == c)flag = 1;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}

int search_arc(graf *gr[], int c1, int c2) {
    int flag = 0;
    if (search_node(gr, c1) && search_node(gr, c2)) {
        int i = 0;
        while (gr[i]->key != c1)
            i++;
        graf *p = gr[i];
        while (p->key != c2 && p->next != NULL)
            p = p->next;
        if (p->key == c2)
            flag = 1;
    }
    return flag;
}

void add_node(graf *gr[], int c) {
    if (search_node(gr, c))
        printf("Edge existing !\n");
    else {
        int j = 0;
        while (gr[j] && (j<N))j++;
        if (gr[j] == NULL) {
            gr[j] = new graf;
            gr[j]->key = c;
            gr[j]->next = NULL;
        }
        else
            printf("Overflow !\n");
    }
}

void add_arc(graf *gr[], int c1, int c2) {
    int i = 0;
    graf *p;
    if (search_arc(gr, c1, c2))
        printf("there is edge from node  %s to node %s", c1, c2);
    else {
        if (!(search_node(gr, c1)))
            add_node(gr, c1);
        if (!(search_node(gr, c2)))
            add_node(gr, c2);
        while (gr[i]->key != c1)
            i++;
        p = new graf;
        p->key = c2;
        p->next = gr[i]->next;
        gr[i]->next = p;
    }
}

int get_graph_rank(graf*& gr,int i=0)
{
    int max = NULL;

    if (gr != NULL)
    {
      //i think to use recursion but i don't know how to start ...
    }

    return max;
}
int main() {
    int c, k;
    int menu = NULL, br = NULL;
    graf *gr1[N];
    init(gr1);
    do
    {
        printf("1. add node\n");
        printf("2. add edge\n");
        printf("3.get the rang\n");
        printf("0. exit\n");
        do {
            scanf_s("%d",&menu);
        } while (menu<0 || menu>4);
        switch (menu) {
        case 1:
            printf("enter edge: ");
            scanf_s("%d", &c);
            add_node(gr1, c);
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("begining edge: ");
            scanf_s("%d", &c);
            printf("ending edge: ");
            scanf_s("%d", &k);
            add_arc(gr1, c, k);
            break;
        case 3:
            get_graph_rank(*gr1);
            break;
        }
    } while (menu != 0);

    delete gr1;
}
```

I hope you could help me write the logic of the function which will return the value of the node ,which has the maximum edges connected to it , and if there is more than one node with the same count of edges connected , return NULL.Thanks in advice .....

Comment: To anyone who's been editing this question: the `new` and `delete` keywords don't exist in C. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/360824/584518

Comment: I have never seen the spelling _graf_ (except when the German word for the nobility title _count_, which is _Graf_, is meant).

Comment: This looks fishy. What happens if all array members are non-NULL and beyond array there happens to be a NULL? `while (gr[j] && (j<N))j++;
        if (gr[j] == NULL) {
            /* writing to gr[j] */
        }`

Comment: @Codor it's written in latin from bulgarian "граф" -> graf

Comment: @J.Rusev I see (I'm just picky out of boredom), but the Cyrillic _ф_ is based on the Greek letter. The Latin alphabet usually transcribes _ph_; however, in the Age of Unicode, this doesn't matter.

Comment: In your kind of graph, any node can only point to one other node. But any node can be pointed to by several nodes. True?

Comment: Did you consider turning this interesting kind of graph into a tree with unrestricted number of childs per node? E.g. use the "left==child/right==sibling" concept. On that structure, achieving your goal would be much easier. If you need the link (opposite direction) just add/keep the single pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the code uses a singly-linked list node for representing graph nodes. That means your nodes cannot have more than 1 (outgoing) edge. Not sure if such a graph representation is useful.

Another way is to represent your graph is use an array for graph node values and represent edges as an [adjacency matrix N-by-N](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) where each element is a bit specifying whether there is an edge from node A to node B.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: @J.Rusev Why do you use such a useless graph representation?